# Notice: Your relay has a very large number of connections to other relays

Tags: help, connection, log

Setup my relay up about 8 hours ago, everything is going fine, no warnings. Then I get this notice. How can I investigate this to determine if the relay is configured and running properly?

> [notice] Your relay has a very large number of connections to other relays. Is your outbound address the same as your relay address? Found 12 connections to 8 relays. Found 12 current canonical connections, in 0 of which we were a non-canonical peer. 4 relays had more than 1 connection, 0 had more than 2, and 0 had more than 4 connections.

Answer (score 1):

So I believe I found the answer to this, in case anyone stumbles across this... According to a thread on Tor's bug tracker, this is "normal" and is only a concern if the number is greater than 60.

Quoting user "theor":

> Feel free to ignore this, if all the numbers are less than 60. (60 is 1% of a relay's 6000 connections to other relays.)
>   Otherwise, please report it.
>
> This message is logged so we can make sure that a relay isn't making too many connections to other relays.
>
> We could change the code so it logs an info-level message when the number of duplicate connections is under 1% of the number of nodes.

Thread: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/24841